# SocketIO blocks server

Tags: express, socket.io

I have a simple app that uses express to serve a static page which creates a socketio connection. The problem is the server stops responding after a minute or two. This is the code:

**server.js**

```
const path = require('path');
const http = require('http');
const express = require('express');
const socketIO = require('socket.io');  
const publicPath = path.join(__dirname, './public');

const port = 3000;

  let app = express();
  let server = http.createServer(app);
  var io = socketIO(server);

  app.get(`/`, (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(publicPath + '/index.html');
  });

  server.listen(port, () => {
    console.log('listening...');
  })

  io.on('connection', (socket) => {
   socket.on('test', (data) => {
    console.log(data);
   });
  });
```

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
  </head>

  <body class="centered">
    <center><h1>This is a test</h1></center>
    <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
    <script>
      var socket = io();
      socket.on('connect', () => {
        socket.emit('test', 'this is some data');
      });
    </script>

  </body>

</html>
```

**Package.json**

```
{
  "name": "test",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "server.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "node server.js"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.16.4",
    "socket.io": "^2.1.1"
  }
}
```

Of course there are no errors on server or client. If i remove the line `var socket = io()` the app runs smoothly.

Comment: you have absolutely no socket.io handling in the server, neither in the frontend, what are your expectation ? you should create some channels and put/read data from/in it, then we can see if the server is really not responding or not.

Comment: @MarwenTrabelsi I added a simple logging on connection on both sides, The logging works fine for a minute or so, and then the server just stops responding.

Comment: you are just connecting the client to the server, there is no real input/output. can you add some events and emit some other ? just to make a real working app, the current code will hangs doing nothing.

Comment: @MarwenTrabelsi Added a custom 'data' event. The server is responding to it, printing the data as expected. As usual, about 1 minute after I connect the server gets stuck.

Comment: interesting, I will try to reproduce it later and post the result, would be nice if you put your package.json as well just in case ;)

Comment: @MarwenTrabelsi Ok, thank you very much! I added package.json :)

Comment: If the server stops responding when you're running this code, the problem is likely to be caused by something outside of Node.js or Express. I see nothing wrong with this code. Perhaps you can specify what exactly you mean by "stops responding"? How do you test that?

Comment: @robertklep When I say it stops responding, I mean that when i try and refresh the page it just loads forever. On the server, there are no errors, it doesn't get the http requests from the browser and I cant stop it with CTRL+C. I have to force close the cmd.

Comment: exactly, I wasn't able to reproduce any issue using that code, i was able to reload for 5 minutes without issues, what kind of env do you have, I guess Windows? a good practice is always to open the chrome dev tools and do refrech & clear cache - just to be sure that you are not victim of cache

Comment: @SagiRika again, I'm pretty sure that this is caused by something outside of Node.js, there's no reason for that to happen with the code that you're posting.

Comment: @MarwenTrabelsi The cache isn't the problem, still doesn't work. I have a friend that use Linux and it worked for him. May I ask what env do you use?

Comment: Osx, but I think it's more interesting to know what is yours

Comment: @MarwenTrabelsi Oh I thought I already said that mine is indeed Windows 10 64-bit :) Also, I have confirmed that it works on another Windows computer. I guess something in my computer iterrupts..

Comment: @SagiRika things to check out are personal firewalls, proxies and antivirus software.

Comment: so the problem is not about the code or at least not anything we could know, this is something related to other problems on OS side.

Comment: @MarwenTrabelsi Yea I get it now. Thank you for your help!